# Can StackExchange sites be whitelabled

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

I saw http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html which looks a clone of SO, but I couldn't find any reference to SO or any affiliations to it mentioned anywhere.

Is this a white labeled StackExchange site or a plain rip-off?

[image]

---

**Update:** I did see in their faq that they recently ***moved*** to QATO:
[image]

So I guess StackExchange allows the sites to be white labeled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It's powered by Qato](http://answers.unity3d.com/page/about.html;jsessionid=9F92973701AFDDF549179F6E8466136B), and [formerly used SE 1.0](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/63033/should-unity-answers-be-migrated-to-qato-or-stay-w.html).  So yeah, they've used an SE ripoff.

**Edit:** If by "white labelled" you mean SE used to licence their software, then yes, they used to.  If you mean they licenced it and allowed the licencee to remove all references to StackExchange from the website, I am pretty sure they did not.

Comment: The wording "ripped off" is a bit hard. The old white-label was discontinued, so they hadn't much choice - either switch to another engine, or try to move to SE 2.0 through Area 51 (which does not really support the same business model).

Comment: @Paulo I was more referring to Qato ripping off SE.  Fixed